# Gradle: run tests from dependency

Tags: java, gradle, jbehave

**I have two projects:**

- Application project --- Project A
- Project with acceptance tests (`on JBehave`) --- Project B

**buid.gradle --- Project B (with jbehave tests):**

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output 
}

artifacts {
    archives sourceJar, testJar
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {  
        if(project.ext.isReleaseVersion){
            repository (url: '[RepUrl]') {
                authentication (userName: 'user', password: 'pass')
            }  
            println "Upload to internal"
        }else{
            snapshotRepository (url: '[RepUrl]') {
                authentication (userName: 'user', password: 'pass')
            }  
            println "Upload to snapshots"
        }

        pom.version = '0.1'
        pom.artifactId = 'acceptance-tests'        
        pom.groupId = 'group' 
}
```

**build.gradle --- project A:**

```
dependencies {
    testRuntime ('group:acceptance-tests:latest.release:tests')
}
```

When I run `gradlew test` int the project A is not carried out a single test.

Tell me, please , where is my mistake.

Comment: Add the tests as a sourceset, not a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

It will not work. The test classes that should be run are configured in the SourceSets. It comes from java plugin. Read this. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html. I don't think that you can configure it to use some dependencies. Maybe you can change the behaviour of test task, you should take a look into source code of test task. Or you can write your own test task. You can also add a new action to test task and run junit to execute your tests with some other tools like ant.junit.